# The Veronese Surface is the only surface of $\mathbb{P}^{5}$ that can be isomorphically projected to $\mathbb{P}^{4}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{5}$ be a surface such that the dimension of its secant variety is $\dim \mathrm{Sec} (X)=4$. In Theorem 3.2.5 of Francesco Russo's book 
*'Tangents and Secants of Algebraic  Varieties: Notes of a Course'* it is proved that $X$ is projectively equivalent to the Veronese Surface $v_{2}(\mathbb{P}^{2})\subset\mathbb{P}^{5}$. The problem is that I don't really understand his proof. It is as follows:

Given a general $z\in \mathrm{Sec}(X)$, 
$$
\Sigma_{z}=\{x\in X:\text{$z$ lies on a secant or tangent line to $X$ passing through $x$}\},
$$
is a conic in the projective plane
$$
C_{z}=\overline{\{p\in\mathbb{P}^{5}:p\in \langle x,z\rangle, \text{with }x\in\Sigma_{z}  \}}=\mathrm{Sec}(\Sigma_{z}).
$$

In addition, if $u\in SX$ is a general point, then the intersection 
$\Sigma_{z}\cap\Sigma_{u}$ is only one point.

We are suppose to be able to construct a birational map 
$$
\phi:X\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{2}
$$
because of this, that sends the conics $\Sigma_{z}$ to lines. Furthermore,  if $i:X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^{5}$ is the inclusion, then 
$$
i \circ\phi^{-1}:\mathbb{P}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{5}
$$
sends conics into lines. This implies that $i \circ\phi^{-1}$ is a morphism given by the  complete linear system $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(2)|$ and therefore $i \circ\phi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism and $X$ is projectively equivalent to $v_{2}(\mathbb{P}^{2})\subset\mathbb{P}^{5}$.

I don't understand the construction of $\phi$ and the subsequent implications. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In [this version](http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/biblioteca/cbm/24CBM/24_CBM_03_11.pdf) of the text cited, it's formulated pretty clearly. There are two pencils of conics constituting a linear system which defines the map.